# valid way to use TOP, ORDER BY and DISTINCT in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is a valid way to write this query?

I need to order the column customer by DocNum descending and get the top 25 without any duplicate.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 customer
FROM tt
WHERE DocNum LIKE '%_%' AND UPPER(U_NAME) NOT LIKE '%E G%'
ORDER BY DocNum DESC
```

Comment: *"What is a valid way to write this query?"* Remove the backslash (`\ `) characters? Then its a valid query.

Comment: `\'%_%\'` (which I assume should be `'%_%'` doesn't seem right either. That's a multi-character wildcard, followed by a single-character wildcard, followed by a multi-character wildcard. So, effectively, any non-zero length string would match the value. Do you actually want `'%[_]%'`?

Comment: The question is, what is the pattern you are looking for? Is the single quote meant to be part of  the pattern? `'_%'` is the same as `'%_%'`. Both mean at least one character. You could also write `LEN(DocNum) > 0`.

Comment: sorry I forgot to delete them, nothing is wrong about those. I made some formatting for my code because I used this query in PHP.  Just DISTINCT + TOP, DISTINCT+TOP+ ORDER BY or any other combination returns null or error @Larnu

Comment: sorry I forgot to delete them, nothing is wrong about those. I made some formatting for my code because I used this query in PHP. Just DISTINCT + TOP, DISTINCT+TOP+ ORDER BY or any other combination returns null or error. I edited the question @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Comment: If you are getting `DISTINCT Customer` then which `DocNum` of the potentially many that were collapsed down to 1 by the distinct should be used for ordering?

Comment: *If* the above isn't returning any rows, then there are no rows where `DocNum` has *at least* one character, and `U_NAME` contains the string `E G`.

Comment: Side note, as well, unless you are in a case sensitive collation (presumably you aren't) then using `UPPER` on your column `U_NAME` in the `WHERE` does nothing other than cause performance degradation. In a case insentivation collation, `'e g'`, `'E g'`, `'e G'`, and `'E G'` would all be `LIKE` and equal (`=`) to each other.

Comment: @Larnu it returns rows without distinct

Comment: `DISTINCT` won't cause your dataset to contain no rows if it did before, @wittream . It can cause it to return *less* rows, but it won't cause it to return none when it did before. I suggest you take the time to create a full [mre] here.

Comment: It should return an error - "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." - maybe your code is just catching that and ignoring it?

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, I understand the problem. Is there a way to say order by docnum then show the top one and discard the others for the ones has the same Customer (if it makes sense)

Comment: Something like `SELECT TOP 25 customer
FROM tt
WHERE DocNum LIKE '%_%' AND U_NAME NOT LIKE '%E G%'
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY MIN(DocNum) DESC`

Comment: The above will make the error go away - I don't know if it will necessarily do what you want though. You should edit the question and provide example data and desired results for what you are attempting to do

Comment: Thank you so much, your query with MAX(DocNum) worked for me! But I wonder if I can do these by first selecting top 25 and then doing the filtering,  reducing/eliminating these 25. Sorry if I am asking too much :) @MartinSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 25 customer 
FROM tt
WHERE DocNum LIKE '%_%' AND 
U_NAME NOT LIKE '%E G%' 
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY MAX(DocNum) DESC
```

works thanks to Martin Smith